# Collect data of DataFrame column in Json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with two column as "key": `id1` and `id2`:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, 11, "n1", "d1"),
  (1, 22, "n2", "d2"),
  (2, 11, "n3", "d3"),
  (2, 11, "n4", "d4")
).toDF("id1", "id2", "number", "data")

scala> df1.show
+---+---+------+----+
|id1|id2|number|data|
+---+---+------+----+
|  1| 11|    n1|  d1|
|  1| 22|    n2|  d2|
|  2| 11|    n3|  d3|
|  2| 11|    n4|  d4|
+---+---+------+----+
```

I want to get Json, grouped by the keys of the dataframe, like this:

```
+---+---+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|id1|id2| json                                                             |
+---+---+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1| 11|[{"number" : "n1", "data": "d1"}]                                 |
|  1| 22|[{"number" : "n2", "data": "d2"}]                                 |
|  2| 11|[{"number" : "n3", "data": "d3"}, {"number" : "n4", "data": "d4"}]|
+---+---+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Versions:

```
Spark: 2.2
Scala: 2.11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by first using [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) to convert the `number` and `data` columns to json format. Then use `groupBy` with [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) on the two id columns to get the wanted result.

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("json", to_json(struct($"number", $"data")))
  .groupBy("id1", "id2").agg(collect_list($"json"))
```

Comment: small and beautiful. Thanks shaido